# Why can't I assign a new value to a dictionary entry?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
var dict = ["name": "ryan", "age": 13, "gender": "male"]
//error on the next line
dict["hairColor"] = "brown"
```

In the tutorial I'm watching the snippet above is working, but not for me. The error says:

> cannot assisgn to the result of this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in older versions of Xcode, such as 6.0.1. It works fine in the latest version, 6.1.1. You should update your Xcode.

You'll also need to `import Foundation` (or import it implicitly through `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`, either of which will also include Foundation) for the code to work, as that allows the compiler to assume you want a dictionary of `NSObject`s, because you're trying to put mixed types (integer and string) into the Dictionary. This complete example works fine in 6.1.1:

```
import Foundation // Or Cocoa, or UIKit

var dict = ["name": "ryan", "age": 13, "gender": "male"]
dict["hairColor"] = "brown"
```

Comment: Yes, in the latest version of Xcode this works without any issues.

Comment: Thats the problem, my xCode was not fully updated. Thank you sir. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice explanation. It helps a lot to the people which still using Xcode 6.0.1.